# Add powerplatform API to Conditional Access Policies and firewall rules

Tags: azure, power-platform

We've detected an issue with your network configuration while accessing Power Platform API Urls. You may experience errors in PPAC until this is resolved. Please add https://api.powerplatform.com and https://*.api.powerplatform.com urls to your Conditional Access policies and to your firewall rules. See all service URLs

Can't see where to add this

Comment: Your Azure AD has conditional access policies and firewalls enabled. You might want to check with your organization azure administrator on how to update a conditional access and firewall rules. Wrong update of policy could impact whole organization's ability to access powerplaform.